# VBA API Call returns value when run on one computer but not on another identical one

Tags: api, vba

I have an API call that returns a value from a foreign listview (Java application) that works just fine on my computer.  When I try to run the same call on my colleague's computer, however, it just returns "0".  We work in an office and our computers are identical--same model, same version of Windows, same version of MS Office (with Excel).  The file with the API call resides on a shared network location, so it is the exact same file, exact same code that I am running on both machines.  I am not very well-versed in API, so I'm probably missing something simple, but I haven't been able to solve it.  Can anyone clue me in to why the code works on one machine but not the other?

Here's the code with the call--see my NOTE about halfway down that shows where I get a discrepancy:

```
Public Function GetListviewItem(ByVal hWindow, pRow) As String

    Dim result              As Long
    Dim myItem              As LV_ITEM
    Dim pHandle             As Long
    Dim pStrBufferMemory    As Long
    Dim pMyItemMemory       As Long
    Dim strBuffer()         As Byte
    Dim index               As Long
    Dim tmpstring           As String
    Dim strLength           As Long
    Dim pColumn As Long
    Dim lProcID As Long

    '**********************
    'init the string buffer
    '**********************
    ReDim strBuffer(MAX_LVMSTRING)
    pColumn = 2
    '***********************************************************
    'open a handle to the process and allocate the string buffer
    '***********************************************************
    GetWindowThreadProcessId hWindow, lProcID ' Get the process ID in which the ListView is running
    If lProcID <> 0 Then
        pHandle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_VM_OPERATION Or PROCESS_VM_READ Or PROCESS_VM_WRITE, False, lProcID)
        pStrBufferMemory = VirtualAllocEx(pHandle, 0, MAX_LVMSTRING, MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE)

        '************************************************************************************
        'initialize the local LV_ITEM structure
        'The myItem.iSubItem member is set to the index of the column that is being retrieved
        '************************************************************************************
        myItem.mask = LVIF_TEXT
        myItem.iItem = pRow
        myItem.iSubitem = pColumn
        myItem.pszText = pStrBufferMemory
        myItem.cchTextMax = MAX_LVMSTRING

        '**********************************************************
        'write the structure into the remote process's memory space
        '**********************************************************
        pMyItemMemory = VirtualAllocEx(pHandle, 0, Len(myItem), MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE)
        result = WriteProcessMemory(pHandle, pMyItemMemory, myItem, Len(myItem), 0)

        '*************************************************************
        'send the get the item message and write back the memory space
        '*************************************************************
    'NOTE: THE 'result' VARIABLE IS WHERE I GET VALUES, BUT THE OTHER COMPUTER GETS '0'

        result = SendMessage(hWindow, LVM_GETITEMTEXTA, pRow, ByVal pMyItemMemory)
        result = ReadProcessMemory(pHandle, pStrBufferMemory, strBuffer(0), MAX_LVMSTRING, 0)
        result = ReadProcessMemory(pHandle, pMyItemMemory, myItem, Len(myItem), 0)

        '**************************************************
        'turn the byte array into a string and send it back
        '**************************************************
        For index = LBound(strBuffer) To UBound(strBuffer)
            If Chr(strBuffer(index)) = vbNullChar Then Exit For
            tmpstring = tmpstring & Chr(strBuffer(index))
        Next index

        tmpstring = Trim(tmpstring)
        '***********************************************
        'deallocate the memory and close the process handle
        '**************************************************
        result = VirtualFreeEx(pHandle, pStrBufferMemory, 0, MEM_RELEASE)
        result = VirtualFreeEx(pHandle, pMyItemMemory, 0, MEM_RELEASE)

        result = CloseHandle(pHandle)

        If Len(tmpstring) > 0 Then GetListviewItem = tmpstring
    End If

End Function
```

Thanks to anyone who might have some suggestions.